Reference request: where was pseudo-dimension introduced?
I've been looking into the topic of pseudo-dimension in learning theory (e.g. here) and I am trying to find out where it was first introduced and first used in learning theory. The earliest reference I could find is Pollard's Lecture notes on Empirical Processes but I'm wondering if anyone knows where it was first introduced (or, if it was first introduced here).

If you don't get an answer here you can try on History of Science and Mathematics.
